# Looking for some way to share images and other media to Facebook (without having the Facebook app installed)

Tags: applications, facebook, share-menu

I've removed the Facebook app from my phone due to it's high drain on the battery (Facebook and Messenger were consuming over 18% of the battery just based on background activity)

Is there some way or method that can provide "share to" functionality to Facebook without having Facebook installed. I'd be fine with it only supporting images, but other media would be great. I know I can use Facebook in Chrome and that might be the answer, but I was hoping for a better solution.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Perhaps Swipe for Facebook? I don't have it installed so I can't verify the functionality.

Comment: @izzy Can you please  explain how I can "describe my situation and the specific problem I am trying to solve"  any more thoroughly.  If I had just said,  I'm looking for "some way"  instead of "an app" would that have avoided getting my question  put on hold?

Comment: @gymbrall That would likely put you in another category (questions that are Android-independent).

Comment: @gymbrall exactly as you did :) Though I very much doubt there is a possibility to share to a website open in a browser, I reopened your question as it's no longer off-topic. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Login to facebook from your moblie browser. Click on the **Photo** at top left of facebook home page. Click **Add photo** or **Add Video** as per your requirement. Then select the content you want to upload.

Comment: I mentioned in my question that I was aware of this method.  For whatever reason it's clunky and a bit annoying at least on my Nexus 6. Maybe that's the best way.  Thanks for answering.

Comment: Sorry I missed it while reading your question. I guess there is one more way to upload photos through email to facebook, I tried that may be a year back, hope this [link](https://www.facebook.com/help/community/question/?id=1483902935194338) can be of some use to you.